# Liquibase force run always

Tags: liquibase

I'm using Liquibase to apply database changes. At some point I deleted everything in the database and then tried to make Liquibase re-run the change log.

My "master" change log file looks like this:

```
databaseChangeLog:
- include:
    relativeToChangelogFile: true
    file: db.changelog-diff-20180620-1733.yaml
```

And db.changelog-diff-20180620-1733.yaml looks like this:

```
databaseChangeLog:
- changeSet:
    runAlways: true
    id: 1529512411141-1
    author: XXXXXX (generated)
    changes:
    - createSequence:
        sequenceName: hibernate_sequence
```

1. I thought I could make Liquibase re-run db.changelog-diff-20180620-1733.yaml by setting runAlways to true. Still Liquibase does not run the change log.
2. I then tried just deleting all the entries the table databasechangelog. That doesn't work either.
3. Tried running Liquibase with the clearCheckSums command.

None of these have worked.

I'm running Liquibase via Gradle. Here's the tasks:

```
task liquibaseDiffChangelog(type: JavaExec) {
    group = "liquibase"

    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    classpath configurations.liquibase
    main = "liquibase.integration.commandline.Main"

    args "--changeLogFile=" + "$projectDir/src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-diff-" + buildTimestamp() + ".yaml"
    args "--referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:uk.xxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx.coh.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect"
    args "--username=" + liquibaseProps.getProperty('username')
    args "--password=" + liquibaseProps.getProperty('password')
    args "--url=" + liquibaseProps.getProperty('url')
    args "--driver=" + liquibaseProps.getProperty('driver')
    args "diffChangeLog"
}

task migratePostgresDatabase(type: JavaExec) {
    group = "liquibase"

    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    classpath configurations.liquibase
    main = "liquibase.integration.commandline.Main"

    def urlString = project.hasProperty("dburl") ? "jdbc:postgresql://$dburl" : liquibaseProps.getProperty('url')
    def user = project.hasProperty("flyway.user") ? "${rootProject.properties['flyway.user']}" : liquibaseProps.getProperty('username')
    def password = project.hasProperty("flyway.password") ? "${rootProject.properties['flyway.password']}" : liquibaseProps.getProperty('password')

    args "--changeLogFile=./src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml"
    args "--username=$user"
    args "--password=$password"
    args "--url=$urlString"
    args "--driver=" + liquibaseProps.getProperty('driver')
    args "update"
}
```

Anyone know how I can force Liquibase to re-run changelogs?

Comment: how are you running liquibase?

Comment: Run from gradle. I've now added the gradle tasks to the original question for clarity

Comment: and do you have some output from tasks?

Comment: The databasechangelog table is the central point that liquibase uses to track was has been run. If you delete/empty it liquibase must think that none of your changes have been applied and do them all again. So this should work. Maybe you deleted the wrong databasechangelog table in a different schema? Is the table filled after you run liquibase again?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses. I eventually gave up on this. I blew away the database, then re-ran the Gradle liquibaseDiffChangelog task to essentially get a clean database build changelog.

So my looks like this i.e. just the one change log file in my master change log file :

```
databaseChangeLog:
- include:
    relativeToChangelogFile: true
    file: db.changelog-diff-20180627-2001.yaml
```

It just seems like less hassle this way.

Thanks again for all the responses